# How to make an auto expand div / span, like a table?

Tags: width, html

So, this is what I want:

```
<span>Field 1</span><span>Field 2</span><span>Field 3</span><br />
<span>Content A1</span><span>Content B1</span><span>Content C1</span><br />
<span>Content A2</span><span>Content B2</span><span>Content C2</span><br />
<span>Content A3</span><span>Content B3</span><span>Content C3</span><br />
```

Now I want that `Field1` has that width as the biggest Constant A1 / Constant A2 / Constant A3 have. In other words, each column auto expand to the maximum width of content. Just like in tables. Is it doable?

Comment: If you have tabular data, why don't you use a `table`?

Comment: set width to in style that will do but again better to use table

Comment: well its another topic :D I was told out of doing that, but I like tables very much. But they considered invalid and rubbish element now

Comment: @JohnSmith It is nowadays seen as bad practise to use `table` for layouting your whole page, but it is still valid in cases, where you really have tabular data.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this css : 
`span{
display: table-cell;
}`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp